# Can i work out DECT base positions based on a wifi penetration survey ?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

We are conducting a wifi penetration survey to assess the best optimal locations to place some wifi access points.

We also need to install a DECT phone system in the same building, we dont have the kit to conduct a DECT penetration survey, but wondered if its required or if we could infer the optimal setting out from the wifi survey  ?

The reason im thinking we might be able to infer the locations from the wifi survey is DECT runs on 1.9ghz so presumably has better penetration that wifi 2.4ghz which in turn has better penetration than 5ghz wifi.

Is that a correct assumption to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you are using to analyze the radio frequencies.
Higher end tools like a spectrum analyzer may be able to do this depending on the frequency range it supports.

If we are talking about using a wireless card, The answer is a simple no.

Your assumptions are correct, the higher the frequency the worse its attenuation is, over the same distances in the air, and the worse it penetrates obstructions.

A cheaper alternative to expensive spectrum analyzers is software defined radio. A RTL-SDR can be picked up on ebay for $8 - $20. Something like the RTL-2832U can show you BELOW the 2.4 ghz WIFI spectrum. Although if i purchased one new again, I would go with one that supported a wider frequency range. But for the price they are a very nice tool to have.

Regards,